# Trying to run a JS script on mac terminal but keep getting NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: node.js, networking, terminal, syntax-error, ethers.js

I am a complete noob and watching a video on ether.js. I am trying to run a script with node.js on my mac terminal but keep getting this error.

**MY CODE**

```
const address = '0xb5d85CBf7cB3EE0D56b3bB207D5Fc4B82f43F511';
const main = async () => {
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
    console.log(`\nETH Balance of ${address} --> ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)} ETH\n`)

main()
```

**RUN ERROR**

```
/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.5.3)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:517:54)
    at step (/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/Users/mac/ethers_examples/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```